# OrientDB combination of edge and vertex properties

Tags: orientdb

I am trying to select a edge "Contained" that points to a "Rgb" vertex, in OrientDB 2.1, with PhpOrient. The edge haves a property "probability", and the Rgb haves a property "hex".

So:

```
Artist -> created -> Artwork -> contained -> Rgb.
```

This query finds the edge "Contained" with the property "probability".

```
SELECT *, EXPAND (OUT("Created").OUTE("Contained")) FROM Artist WHERE path="Achebach, Andreas"
```

This query finds the vertex Rgb with the property "hex".

```
SELECT *, EXPAND (OUT("Created").OUT("Contained")) FROM Artist WHERE path="Achebach, Andreas"
```

But I want to have both properties. How can I combine the queries to have one query, that can find both properties?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In v 2.1 you can do it with a subquery:

```
SELECT probability, inV().hex FROM (
   SELECT expand(out("Created").outE("Contained")) 
   FROM Artist WHERE path="Achebach, Andreas"
)
```

In OrientDB v 2.2 you can also do it with pattern matching

```
MATCH
  {class:Artist, as:a, where:(path="Achebach, Andreas")}
  .out("created"){as:aw}
  .outE("contained"){as:cont}
  .inV(){as:rgb}
RETURN cont.probability, rgb.hex
```